# How to notify when an App is uninstalled to backend?

Tags: python, android, ios, amazon-web-services, mobile-application

I have an application where I perform some background tasks once the user has selected permission for that in the app. I cannot give the exact scenario here.

But consider, that once a user logs in and gives access to an external data source unless the user disconnects from our app we can still continue to get the data.

Here, the permission given by the user is stored as 1/0 in the backend and if connection_permission is 1 backend will keep collecting the data. For collecting data we use an AWS Lambda CRON job that runs every N hours.

Here, the concern that I have is that whenever a user uninstalls the APP from the device or signs out from the app without disconnecting permission, the backend will still have permission to collect data.

So there are a few solutions that we are looking at :

1. This is more of a check. We always check for user_active timestamp and if timestamp > a threshold we disconnect from the backend automatically.
2. Send a dry push notification to the user device, FCM will return 'not registered' as a response if an application is uninstalled or if fails to deliver, this can also be not delivered in case of other issues also.
3. Disconnect users by running a script on user uninstall (Since uninstall is an OS level event is there a way to run a script on uninstall. This will also be a problem if the user uninstalls the app without connecting to the internet, we will not be able to reach the backend)

Note: We have this application running in both ANDROID and IOS.

Comment: #3 is not an option. There is no way to run an "uninstall script".

Comment: A combination of #1 and #2: maybe 5 or 10 missed push notification over the period of a few days *and* and old timestamp.